# HTML YouTube video embed throws out js errors and downloads video on when viewed in mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to embed YouTube videos in my website. The recommended method to do that is by using an iframe. Because the videos in my site are dynamic, I use php to display them. Here's the code I use to display them.

```
$videoFrame = '<iframe id="ytplayer" class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="'.$width.'"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'?rel=0&showinfo=0&color=red&iv_load_policy=3"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

This method, using YouTube.com/embed, allows the video to work on mobile, but I get a lot of Chromecast extension js errors which messes with some of the js on my page.

I've read here on stackoverflow, that you can fix this by instead using YouTube.com/v/, this works, but when I access my site on my phone, the video ID gets downloaded. I get a message saying (for example: if the URL is YouTube.com/v/abcdef) this site is trying to download multiple files, with the filename being "abcdef".

What do I do? Are there any other methods with which I could display YouTube videos? Or how do I fix these methods?

Any help is greatly appreciated.